# How to add New payment method (credit card) in magento 2

Tags: payment-methods, magento2.2.6, credit-card

I wish to add new **payment method** for **credit cards**.
How do I add **Credit card** as a new payment method in **magento 2**.
Please Provide me a solution to customize **payment methods**

Comment: For Offline Payment method, https://www.rakeshjesadiya.com/create-custom-payment-method-using-adapter-class-magento-2/

Answer (score 1):

Use this link for creating custom payment method in Magento 2

1) https://www.classyllama.com/blog/how-to-create-payment-method-magento-2 To get the code directly from [here](https://github.com/chris-huffman/LlamaCoin)

2) https://webkul.com/blog/add-cc-form-custom-payment-method-magento2/

Answer (score -2):

You can refer this module: https://github.com/stableaddons/ccpp-credit-card

It use credit card form with 2c2p payment gateway

Comment: link is now broken..